# Rails Paperclip File Type Validation - Add PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have the validation setup for only allowing png, and jpg, but I would also like to allow PDF's.  I cannot seem to figure out how to add that syntax to the existing code.

```
  has_attached_file :receipt
  # Validate content type
  validates_attachment_content_type :receipt, :content_type => /\Aimage/
  # Validate filename
  validates_attachment_file_name :receipt, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I have in my code for a similar project...

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf']
```

(Obviously you would take the gif out)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf']
```